# How do I make Opera 10 start without any open tabs?

Tags: opera

I am currently test-driving Opera 10 and the first thing that irks me is that I don't seem to be able to make it start without any open tabs. I also don't want speed dial. Just Opera without any tabs open.

Is this even possible in version 10?

Comment: Thanks for the close vote! This is my first one and I'll treasure it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Tools > Preferences > Advanced > Tabs > Addition Tab Options` - check `Allow Window with no tabs`.

Then, in the `General` tab of the Preferences, you will see `Start Opera without Open Tabs` as an option in the `startup` field. Select that and Opera will start without open tabs.

Comment: Wow. What a usability nightmare! But very good advice, Dan.

Comment: I guessing they think that Opera without tabs would be more of a usability nightmare for ordinary users.