# Open Opera without last session tabs open

Tags: browser, tabs, opera

I am using the following Opera version:

Version:    21.0.1432.67 - Opera is up to date

Update stream:  Stable

System: Windows 8.1 64-bit (WoW64)

I am aware of this answer but it's not applicable in this Opera version [a link] ([How do I make Opera 10 start without any open tabs?](https://superuser.com/questions/33761/how-do-i-make-opera-10-start-without-any-open-tabs))

I belive that I found the place to change the settings.

[image]

The issue is that the settings don't get saved after I exit the settings page.

- Opera > Settings
- I search for "Startup" keyword
- I select "Open a specific page or set of pages".
- I set the page page to "http://www.google.ca"
- I click OK
- I exit the settings page
- I leave (3-4 tabs) open
- I close Opera
- I open Opera
- The last session tabs load

Any idea why this is happening or how to save the settings? I don't see any buttons to OK or Save the setting before exiting the Settings page.

Comment: Download [Opera 23 Developer](http://blogs.opera.com/desktop/), install it in portable mode and try it again. This doesn't touch your existing Opera. It's just a quick check 1) for a bug which is fixed in the latest v23 version or 2) it's a corrupt profile. Because I cannot reproduce your behavior with my Opera 23

Comment: @downvoter: I see no problem with this question. Please explain your concerns and leave a comment

Comment: @nixda - Thanks for the tip. Reinstalling the browser resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As nixda suggested, there was probably a corrupted profile. 
Reinstalling the Opera Browser resolved the issue.